# Как найти функцию обработки события onchange или другого события?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу посмотреть как обрабатываются события нажатия кнопки.

Каким образом мне можно найти эту функцию `onchange="selmarshClick(this)"`?

Comment: `ctrl+f`  - по файлам

Comment: Возможно среда разработки, которую вы используете позволяет осуществлять поиск функции кликнув по ним мышью с нажатием какой-то клавиши на клавиатуре (нужно смотреть применительно к среде разработке) ну или описанный выше способ

Comment: Я рассматриваю сайт в браузером окне.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если нажать <kbd>F12</kbd> в *Chrome* и зайти на вкладку `Sources`, то можно увидеть панель со вкладками, которые помогают при отладке. Одной из таких вкладок будет `Event Listener Breakpoints`, в которой можно назначить в качестве триггера любые события, при которых исполнение скрипта будет остановлено. Выбирай на вкус.

В данном случае нужно будет выбрать `Control` → `change`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для *Firefox* нужно зайти в Инспектор, найти тот самый элемент, в котором прописано событие и обнаружить рядом значок `em`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликнув на него, как утверждает **[developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners)** можно увидеть строчки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где можно увидеть события, навешанные на элемент, скрипт, строку, возможность нажать на паузу и т.д.

Если в *Firefox* нет кнопки паузы, как обещают, то можно попробовать посмотреть во вкладку `Debugger`(отладчик) и попробовать найти стрелку, при наведении на которую будет написано "Events". Там уже должно быть событие этого элемента.

А вот таких полезных вкладок как у *Chrome* к сожалению у *Firefox* я не вижу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кстати, ты ж делал ответы по поиску ошибок, может дубликатом бахнуть?

Comment: Но это же не вопрос по поиску ошибок) Кстати, я там еще не писал про `Event Listener Breakpoints`. Надо дополнить чтоль будет как-нибудь)

Comment: Использую браузер Firefox и я не вижу эту вкладку. 
Пожалуйста, Вы не могли бы уточнить как её найти?

Comment: @112Legion ах да, потому что это Chrome

Comment: @112Legion написал для FF и дал ссылку. Но у меня кнопки паузы не высвечивается в нем. Вообще предпочитаю дебаг в хроме.  У него есть всё для этого

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я также не обнаружиль у себя данной кнопки, но я пожалуй просто скачаю хром.

Comment: @112Legion нашел кажется как можно найти события на элементе у FF. Добавил в ответ. Ну и ерунда же этот firefox :-/