# Как в chrome devtools найти откуда будет вызвана функция прописанная в onclick аттрибуте?

Tags: javascript, html, отладка, атрибуты, google-chrome-devtools

Собственно суть вопроса в топике.

Открываю сайт доставшийся по наследству и вижу в devtools следующую картину:

```
<div onclick="somefunc()">Some text</div>
```

*При нажатии перерисовываются маршруты и метки на карте.*

**Вопрос** Как определить в каком файле и на какой строке объявлена функция вызываемая при клике на вышеупомянутый див?

Для решения поставленной задачи, конечно, можно воспользоваться полнотекстовым поиском по всей кодовой базе и найти все вхождения "someFunc". Но... неее.
Я ищу более цивилизованный способ ведь таких кнопок на сайте туева хуча - это похоже любимый подход того автора. 
Да и мне на будущее думаю будет полезно знать как такое отлавливать.
Есть у меня на вооружении ещё один способ обнаружения, но хочу почитать ваши варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Функции, указанные в атрибутах, всегда глобальные. Поэтому пишешь в консоли `somefunc`, а потом кликаешь на выведенную функцию и попадаешь в то место, где она объявлена. Ну уж если она окажется результатом какого-нибудь bind'а и отобразится как native code, то тебе не повезло и придётся копаться более глубоко.

Comment: У меня при запуске в консоли `somefunc()` пишется `false`, и в браузере открывает модальное окно. Т.е. просто функция выполняется выводя результат. На её объявление не перейти. Браузер Chromium (Chrome).
Как это сделать?

Comment: @bl79, а ты `somefunc` и `somefunc()` отличаешь?

Comment: @bl79, а для функций, которые повешены не так, есть [другой ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705784/178988).

Comment: Спасибо, думал опечатка. )

Answer (score 0):

Как написал в комментарии *Алексей Шиманский*, мой вопрос оказался дубликатом этого: [Каким образом мне можно найти функцию оброботки событи onchange?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705768/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8-onchange)
Я его не нашёл поэтому и создал свой.

Похоже что на данный момент это лучшее решение, хотя если у вас "событийный ад" - куча слушателей на одном событии, то добираться до нужного можно долго. Но не будем о крайностях.

**Мой вариант**, о котором я упоминал в конце вопроса работает **только** если вы знаете что происходит после вызова функции: изменение DOM, аякс-запросы и тп. 
В таком случае можно, соответственно, повесить брейкпоинт на изменение элемента в дом или на вкладке Network отфильтровать xhr-запросы.

В любом случае я знаю только эти 2 способа, не считая Ctrl+F по папке проекта.

Comment: Вообще-то есть событие `click`. Есть в том списке.