# Как узнать, какая javascript функция срабатывает при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: javascript

Я открываю страницу, нажимаю кнопку- как узнать, какая именно функция отработала при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти функцию обработки события onchange или другого события?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705768/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-onchange)

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько способов.
Первый - написать `debugger;` в начале скрипта и проследить как работает скрипт строка за строкой в консоле.

Второй - внути javascript скрипта элемент наверняка выбирается в ввиде `var button=document.getElementById(...)` и тд. Через эту строку можно найти `button.addEventListener(..)`