# Как узнать какой JS скрипт дал элементу CSS свойства

Tags: javascript, css

Приветствую уважаемые! Подскажите как узнать какой js скрипт дал свойства элементу инлайново.
В браузере просто указано что element.style и идет список стилей, но вот какой именно скрипт их ему дал я и хотел бы узнать. Спасибо за Ваши ответы.
http://joxi.ru/v29DEGJiGX0Y8m

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти функцию обработки события onchange или другого события?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705768/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-onchange-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так: в Хроме

1. Выберите нужный элемент
2. Клик правой кнопкой мыши. Выберите `Break on...` потом `attribute modification`. Слева должен появится синий кружок.
3. Обновите страницу или сделайте те действия которые приводят к изменениям (клик, скролл и т.д)

Когда атрибут изменится, с помощью скрипта, браузер откроет его на нужном участке кода

Comment: да действительно крутой способ, спасибо!