# Как в jQuery узнать, какая кнопка мыши вызвала событие blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть обработчик события `blur`. Можно как-то узнать, что именно вызвало это событие? В идеале какая кнопка его вызвала.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти функцию обработки события onchange или другого события?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705768/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-onchange-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как это поможет?

Answer (score 0):

например добавив красную окантовку этому тегу.

```
$( ".target" ).blur(function() {
 $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
});
```

Comment: Это добавить окантовку на элемент, к которому применён blur, а мне нужно понять, что именно вызвало blur, какая кнопка мыши например..