# Как остановить выполнение JS кода в браузере что бы посмотреть стили блока который появился?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, браузер

Есть динамический лоадер который не прописан в разметке первоначально, через 10 секунд после появления исчезает и разметка скрывается. Может можно остановить работу скрипта через панель разработчика либо как то еще добраться к разметке и стилям этого блока?

Comment: Если сможешь найти этот файл в разделе Sources, поставь Breakpoints в какой нибудь из первых строк, перезагрузись и перейди в раздел Элементов, пока код зависнет.

Comment: попробуй так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705784/191482

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало в хроме!