# Как отслеживать все слушатели событий js?

Tags: javascript, callback, javascript-events

Есть ли способ узнавать о всех сработавших обработчиках событий? Нужно узнать имя коллбэк функции или другую информацию. При этом нельзя добавлять что-то в код колбэк функций в обработчиках.

Comment: События работают всегда. Другой вопрос, есть ли обработчик этого события. Если в обработчике нет вывода инфо, что он запущен, то не узнать. Обработчики так же могут динамически создаваться и удаляться. Так же обработчиком может быть анонимная функция

Comment: @SwaD  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705768/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В инспекторе же видны события элемента, а не "все сработавшие".  С одной стороны ответ показывает, где посмотреть, что есть, с другой, не отвечает на вопрос - что из этого сработало. Однако это лучше, чем ничего

Comment: @SwaD поставить галочки на все события, потом что-то сделать  с элементом и дальше смотреть когда дебаг влючится..